# Laravel eloquent 3rd level relationship sorting

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models, the **down_handlers**, **handler** and **handler_timesheet**.
the **handler_timesheet** is a function under **Down_handler**. looks like this.

```
public function handler_timesheet() {
    return $this->hasMany(Handler_timesheet::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Here is my code for joining those 3 models.

```
$handlers = Handler::with(['down_handlers', 'down_handlers.handler_timesheet'])->get();
```

and the result will look like this:

[image]

My question is, how I can sort the record (over all records when it is being displayed as table) using the **created_at** field on the 3rd level relationship(under handler_timesheet). Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Do you want to sort `Handler` by `handler_timesheet` relationship?

Comment: if you will display that record into a table or query in MySQL using join, this will be 4 rows. How can I sort those records by created_at even there are different handlers. Sorry for unclear question

Comment: Please Clear your Question, then we will help you. if your Question is clear then we will give a proper answer.

Comment: @aiipee you want to sort `handler_timesheet` values by `created_at` date?